# Reduce page margin while using bioinfo.cls

Tags: margins

I'm using the bioinfo.cls for my paper and the margins are just too wide. The sample pdf file the publication provided doesn't seem to have this problem(named Sample.pdf; the complete template can be found here: https://academic.oup.com/DocumentLibrary/Bioinformatics/cabios-template.zip). However, when I try to compile the main.tex file, I get margins that are too wide. I tried using the using the geometry package, but the margins are even worse with it.

All the files are accessible at this Sharelatex project: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5887a3ff3cc6276117061161

Thanks!

Comment: normal advice is not to mess with settings of publisher provided classes.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer. I was wondering why the margins are wider when I compile the .tex file as opposed to the publisher provided sample.pdf (of what the complied file should look like), which seems to have different margin width.

Comment: Is the page size definitely the same? (it is size of text block that matters, not the margins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A publisher's class will set the text block for a size suitable for their final journal production, as such the margins when printed on standard A4 or US Letter sized paper are essentially arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

In `bioinfo.cls`, replace line

```
\ExecuteOptions{b4paper,nocrop,centre,info}
```

with

```
\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,nocrop,centre,info}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!